# Change backround to image on windows 8 app development using HTML

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

I was creating an app using grid app template and put the image in the images folder. 
When I tried to change the background image, it didn't work.

This is my code :

**HMTL**

```
<div id="contenthost" data-win-control="Application.PageControlNavigator" data-win-options="{home: '/pages/groupedItems/groupedItems.html'}"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#contenthost {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background:url(../images/Background.jpg);
}
```

Comment: You need to show your HTML.

Comment: this is my html on default.html 
`<div id="contenthost" data-win-control="Application.PageControlNavigator" data-win-options="{home: '/pages/groupedItems/groupedItems.html'}"></div>`

Comment: it work when i change the background color. but for background image it didn't

Comment: What does JavaScript have to do with this?

Comment: Path is probably wrong...

Comment: the path is Visual Studio 2012\Projects\myTemplate\images. javascript on default.html is didn't change

Comment: Does it work if you write the height in pixels instead? It could be that 100% height is 100% of 0.

Comment: i was try to change that to be 
`background:url(../images/Background.jpg) 100% 100%;`
but still don't work

Comment: @user2444960 - if it works with a background color but not the image, either something is wrong with the path (maybe filename?) or the background image is being overridden elsewhere with another selector.

Comment: the path of the file is  Visual Studio 2012\Projects\myTemplate\images
and on the css `background:url(../images/Background.jpg);`    
what's the meaning of the background image is being overridden elsewhere with another selector ? i don't change at all the grid app template, just try change the background to image

Comment: Use Chrome Inspector and see if that image path is found.  Then work from there.

Comment: can't use chrome, must use Visual Studio

Comment: problem solved, the answer is `background-image: url('/Background.jpg');`. i found the solution after i use Blend for Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

First, put your path in the url value in single quotes. Second, using ../images/... is a relative path that relies on the folder structure of your project and therefore your package, and gets tricky when using page controls. Just use /images/... (no leading ..) and you'll reference that folder just fine.

That is, try background:url('/images/background.jpg');

Comment: i was use this background:url('/images/background.jpg');  
but still doesn't work

Comment: It's possible that whatever content is inside the contentHost div is occupying 100% of width and height with no transparency, in which case you won't see any background image. However, it looks like you're just using the Grid App template, but I just tried the same thing with a background image and it showed up just fine. Are you sure it's background.jpg and not background.png? Is the image a valid one? Does the page control have transparent areas?